# Minimum number of rows in a mod 12 multiplication table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Minimum number of rows you would need to write out in a mod 12 multiplication table to guarantee you wrote out an element with an inverse?

I would think this would be just one row as 1 is its own inverse.

Comment: But perhaps the question is, if you just picked rows out of a hat, how many would you have to pick to be sure you had picked one with an inverse.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the multiplication table modulo $12$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccccccc}
\times & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & \bf\color{red} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
3 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 9 \\
4 & 0 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 4 & 8 \\
5 & 0 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 8 & \bf\color{red} 1 & 6 & 11 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 7 \\
6 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 \\
7 & 0 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 4 & 11 & 6 & \bf\color{red} 1 & 8 & 3 & 10 & 5 \\
8 & 0 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 8 & 4 \\
9 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 9 & 6 & 3 \\
10 & 0 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
11 & 0 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & \bf\color{red} 1 \\
\end{array}$$

There are $4$ rows containing a $1$ (the invertible elements modulo $12$ are $\{1,5,7,11\}$).

So we would need to write $12-4+1=9$ distinct rows before we could guarantee writing out a row of an invertible element  (assuming an adversary is choosing the rows that we write out).

In general, we would need to write out $$n-\varphi(n)+1,$$ where $\varphi$ is the [Euler phi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), to guarantee writing out a row of an invertible element.